# Why does a spoon form a virtual image though it is a concave mirror?

Tags: optics, everyday-life, reflection

Concave mirrors always form real image except when the object is between pole and focus..also why do we always get an enlarged image in concave mirror

Answer (score 2):

Note the focal length of the spoon will be only a few centimetres if that.

If you can get close enough so that your face is closer than the focal length of the spoon then you would see a magnified and upright image which is virtual.
This is the arrangement used for a shaving or make up mirror but they have larger focal lengths.

[image]

However you are more likely to be seeing a diminished and inverted image which is **real** and located between your face and the spoon.
Your face will be greater than two focal length from the spoon.

[image]

The real image appears to be in the vicinity of the spoon but you can located by using the no-parallax method as described [here for a concave mirror](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/319515/104696) and [for a convex lens here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/314564/104696) which can be adapted for the spoon.
Such attempts at the location of the real image will be more difficult because of the aberrations caused by the non-spherical shape of the spoon.

I have used the images from [this website](http://www.physicstutorials.org/home/optics/reflection-of-light/curved-mirrors/concave-mirrors/image-formation-in-concave-mirrors).